# Android - Referencing Additional Folders

Tags: android

I have a directory of .txt files that I would like to use in my Android project.  I have tried adding them to the project directory and referencing them from there but it seems that it doesnt know they exist.

I know I can put them in the folder `raw` but i have some .wav files in there and would rather store them somewhere else.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have  you tried the `assets` directory?

Comment: Inside the res folder?

Comment: Outside. - http://i.stack.imgur.com/22tmY.png

Comment: Create the directory `assets` if it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put them in a folder called `assets`:

[image: This is where assets belongs to]

You can now access your files like this:

```
String file = "folder/mytext.txt";
InputStream input = context.getAssets().open(file);
```

Also see [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html).

Comment: Inside the res folder?

Comment: It's in the root of your project, see screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

you can put them in asset folders.  You can not create your own hieararchy.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Path to Assets folder Context.getAssets
       // getContext().getAssets()
       // getAssets() - Return an AssetManager instance for your application's package.
```

//  File file = new File(getAssets()+"myFileName.txt"); // Error

```
        // file to inputstream
        InputStream input = getAssets().open("myData.txt");
        // myData.txt can't be more than 2 gigs.
        int size = input.available();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
        input.read(buffer);
        input.close();

        // byte buffer into a string
        String text = new String(buffer);
```

Try this code
link to that reference is 
http://android.okhelp.cz/get-assets-folder-path-and-read-txt-file-to-string-android-example-code/