# Accessing files in assets folder

Tags: java, android

if i access file from assets folder using Input stream like

```
InputStream is = getAssets().open("errorMapperConfig.xml");
```

I am getting `NullPointerException`, help me in solving this.

Comment: I am using this line of code in a parse function in java class

Comment: It would appear that `getAssets()` is returning null.

Comment: Did you properly create the assets folder? Have a look at my answer  here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20501733/1208581

Comment: yes,but how can i access file in assets folder in java class which does not extends activity?i could able to get output if i use same function in activity,but when i have that function in java class and call that function from activity i am getting null pointer exception

Answer (score 2):

Use `Context` variable to `getAssetes();`

```
AssetManager mngr = myContext.getAssets();
InputStream is = mngr.open("errorMapperConfig.xml");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void readFiles() {
           try
           {
            AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
            InputStream inputStream;
            inputStream = assetManager.open("webpages/how-to-use.html");

            String detail=loadTextFile(inputStream);
            webView.loadData(detail, "text/html", "utf-8");

           }
           catch(Exception e){
               Log.e("Exception ","======>"+e.toString());
             }
        }

    public String loadTextFile(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        byte[] bytes = new byte[4096];
        int len = 0;
        while ((len = inputStream.read(bytes)) > 0)
          byteStream.write(bytes, 0, len);
        return new String(byteStream.toByteArray(), "UTF8");
      }
```

I hope this will help.Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You will have to pass the context of the main activity to this class. Put the code below in the `onCreate()` method of the class with the activity:

```
Context context = getApplicationContext();
```

Then, replace your code tih this:

```
InputStream is = context.getAssets().open("errorMapperConfig.xml");
```

Don't forget you have to have a file named `errorMapperConfig.xml` inside a folder named `assets` in the root of your project.

See the documentation of [getApplicationContext()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getApplicationContext%28%29).